# Problems in the buildgralde to start app in flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, build.gradle

The project was working fine, the only thing I did was to change the branch to the master branch to match it with develop, after doing that and then develop again the project would not start anymore and I got this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LWPW.png)

I have already changed all the versions suggested by android studio but it still doesn't work, it says it can't find the firebase sessions dependency but that dependency has never been used in the project, I added it and still it doesn't let me run it, I have 2 PC that were working exactly the same, in one it keeps running normal but in the other it just doesn't run after changing the branch.